# Approximation of stochastic integrals by Riemann sums

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I know that for $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, the Riemann Integral converges in the sense that
$$\sum_{k=1}^Kf(t_k)(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\longrightarrow \int_0^1f(t)dt$$
as the grid becomes smaller and smaller.

For some diffusion process $X_t$ and some function $f$, does $$\sum_{k=1}^Kf(t_k)(X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k=1}}) \longrightarrow\int_0^1f(t)dX_t$$
and in which sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first important thing to notice is that we cannot expect convergence for fixed $\omega$, i.e. the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^K f(t_k) (X_{t_k}(\omega)-X_{t_{k-1}}(\omega))$$

does in general not converge as $K \to \infty$. Recall the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $\alpha: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. If $$A(f) := \int_a^b f(t) \, d\alpha(t) := \lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^K f(t_{k-1}) (\alpha(t_k)-\alpha(t_{k-1}))$$ exists for all continous $f$, then $\alpha$ is of bounded variation.

Since a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has infinite variation, this lemma shows that the Riemann sums

$$\sum_k f(t_k) (B_{t_k}(\omega)-B_{t_{k-1}}(\omega))$$

do (in general) not even converge for continuous $f$.

That's why Itô came up with a new idea: Let's consider the $L^2$-limit, i.e. define the stochastic integral as

$$\int_0^T f(t) \, dB_t := L^2-\lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^k f(t_{k-1}) (B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}).$$

Using martingale techniques, one can show that this limit does indeed exist for a large class of functions $f$ and today that's the usual way to define stochastic integrals with respect to stochastic processes. Note that $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probability, so we have in particular

$$\sum_{k=1}^k f(t_{k-1}) (B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}) \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\to} \int_0^T f(t) \, dB_t.$$

The so-defined stochastic integral is well-defined for all functions $f:[0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ which are progressively measurable and satisfy the integrability condition

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T f(s)^2 \, ds \right) < \infty.$$

Comment: What is $L^2$ limit. Is it $\lim_{K\to\infty}\left\|\int_0^Tf(t)dB_t - \sum_{k=1}^Kf(t_{k-1})(B_{t_k} - B_{t_{k-1}})\right\|_{L^2} = 0$?

Comment: @Laimond Yes, exactly.