# Why the stochastic integral is a $L^2$ convergence ? Pointwise convergence doesn't work?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

We define $$\int_{0}^Tf(X_t,t)dB_t:=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(X_{t_{i-1}},t_{i-1})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i}),$$
where the limit is taken in $L^2$,  $\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ is a partition of $[0,T]$ s.t. $\max_{i=0,...,n-1}|t_{i+1}-t_i|\to 0$.

Why do we take the limit in $L^2$ ? The pointwise limit doesn't work ? (or the convergence almost surely) If no, I don't really see why... Could someone explain ?

Comment: No, pointwise doesn't work. Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1043851/36150)

Comment: @saz: Thank you very much. Very clear answer. This integral is now more difficult to interpret than before... I hope, once I'll understand the intuition behind this construction, because is very weird for me... I really don't get the point !